# Faster searching many patterns in many files?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, search

First: I have a multiple text files in various dirs and three extentions. All have in path year. Example

```
file20200102
```

Second: I have a list of patterns. It's 2.500 patterns in one txt file. They are just one word names like for example:

```
asd-ddds223
bower3300
...
```

In text files I have a data looks that (379 files):

```
XXXXXXXX bower3300 YYYYYYYY
...
```

Files have totaly different sizes. One can have 20Kb, another 300mb.

I need to find all lines where pattern exist, and put it to new output file.
It coudl be 2.500 x 40.000 users (coz YYYYYY is user id).

I write a working solution. Main method looks that:

```
def create_SNP_list(target_str):
    filesList_g = filesList()
    found = []
    target = target_str
    print("Searching for: {} patterns".format(len(target_str)) )
    print("Supported extends: 'txt, csv, xz, gz'. May works with others text files but not supported.")
    #Extension block
    ext = []
    for l in filesList_g:
        ext.append(l.rsplit('.', 1)[1])
    ext = list(set(ext))
    print("Found files extends", ext)
    #print("List of Files", filesList_g )

    counter_current = 1
    counter_stop = len(filesList_g)

    for file_path in filesList_g:

        for t in target:

            #print("Current t is {} and current target is: {}".format(t, target)
            #print('{}/{}'.format(counter_current,counter_stop))

            counter_current+=1
            #print("current pattern is {}".format(pattern))
            try:
                if '.xz' in file_path:
                    #print("file_path = ", file_path)
                    with lzma.open(file_path, mode='rt') as src:
                        for line in src:
                            if t in line:
                                line = line.rstrip("\n")+ ",{}\n".format(file_path)
                                found.append(line)

                elif '.gz' in file_path:
                    with gzip.open(file_path,'rt') as src:
                        for line in src:
                            if t in line:
                                line = line.rstrip("\n")+ ",{}\n".format(file_path)
                                found.append(line)

                elif '.txt' in file_path or '.csv' in file_path:
                    with open(file_path,'r',encoding='UTF-8') as src:
                        for line in src:
                            if t in line:
                                line = line.rstrip("\n")+ ",{}\n".format(file_path)
                                found.append(line)

                #print("*"*10 + "DEBUG" + "*"*10)
                #print("current Found table is = {}".format(found))
                #print("*" * 10 + "END" + "*" * 10)

            except:
                print("Something is wrong with open file:", file_path, +'. File will be omitted.')
                try:
                    with open('logs.txt', 'a') as f:
                            f.write("%s/n" % file_path)
                except:
                    print(errorCommunicate)

    print("len of found list = ", len(found))
    return found
```

And now: `fileList_G` is list of paths to 379 files. `target` is a list of 2.500 patterns so `t` is one, current pattern.

Script working fine... I mean, it's works... but one one pattern finding takes ~6min. So... it's 6*2.500. Tooo long :)

Maybe some of You have an idea how to speed it up? Every hint will be awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have calculated the complexity of your solution which which is quadratic, as you check for each line of your files if any of the 2500 patterns exists each line costs O(2500 * lengthOfPattern * lengthOfTheCheckedLine) and for the whole program you will need to multiply by the sum of number of lines of all the files which will result in a very huge number.

So if you want to check if any of these multiple patterns exists in any of the lines you may use an algorithm like [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) which will convert your quadratic approach into a linear time approach!

when you use the Aho-Corasick algorithm the total complexity of your solution will be O(lengthOfAllPatterns+ lengthOfAllLines + LengthOfmatchedPatterns) which I believe will show remarkable difference in the solution performance.